# Java cast Short to Integer using brackets

Tags: java, netbeans, casting

I have the following code that has primitive wrapper classes:

```
// setValue expects Integer (class)
// getValue returns Short (class)
intLength.setValue(shortLength.getValue());
```

Netbeans flags this as an error "incompatible types: Short cannot be converted to Integer", and I get a compile error, which makes sense.

However if I add an extra set of brackets:

```
// setValue expects Integer (class)
// getValue returns Short (class)
intLength.setValue((shortLength.getValue()));
```

The error disappears and the code compiles and works. Can anyone tell me what the extra brackets are doing/why do the brackets do the casting.
Thanks.

Comment: please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Compilation always fails, as expected. Adding extra parenthesis doesn't make a difference. Tested with Eclipse compiler, JDK 1.8.0_91 compiler, JDK 1.8.0_151 compiler, and JDK 9.0.1 compiler.

Comment: well, you're saying `getValue()` returns short, and `setValue(int)` expects int, according to this there should be no compile time error, because short is upcasted to int implicitly

Comment: Could not reproduce with either Eclipse and Intellij jdk1.8.0_92

Comment: Correct way to handle conversion: `intLength.setValue(shortLength.getValue().intValue());`

Comment: @Abd-ElrahmanAdel Not `int`, but `Integer`.

Comment: @Andreas I tested with Short and Integer class, not the primitive types.

Comment: @ZacharyThompson Me too, because that's what question says.

Comment: @Andreas oh I got it, I just tested it, and my netBeans behave just like the question says, I can't understand this :D

Comment: So maybe OP uses NetBeans (would be nice if he'd said so), and NetBeans is flawed, i.e. doesn't follow the Java specs. Specifically, adding parenthesis does not in any way change the type of an expression, as stated in [JLS 15.8.5 Parenthesized Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5).

Comment: @Andreas You're very true bro, I just tried it manually using javac and java commands and it gave me compile time error each time

Answer (score 1):

So as Andreas told in the comments; It's a NetBeans problem, NetBeans doesn't always follow the java specs, because if you checked the [Java Language Specificate, Parenthesized Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5) , it doesn't change the type at all.

You can check that code manually, using javac and java commands and you'll receive a compilation error the both times.

Thanks to Andreas

Answer (score -1):

```
short numShort = 15;
int numInt = (int) new Short(numShort);
```

or in your case

```
intLength.setValue( (int) new Short(shortLength.getValue()));
```

Comment: OP didn't want an answer for short to integer casting, he asked for what parentheses are doing.

Comment: Really..? Isn't what says in the title?

Comment: Title is just title, it doesn't have to be question. Please read the post carefully